# setPopupPosition not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api-client

I have the following code that basically works, but the dialog box is not located where the setPopupPosition method says it should be. I am testing this on Chrome.

```
function doGet() {
  var member1 = "Member1";
  var member2 = "Member2";
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var vPanel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('vPanel').setSpacing(10);
  var hPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel().setId('hPanel').setSpacing(10);
  var msg = app.createHTML("Which member's information do you want to update?");
  var radio1 = app.createRadioButton('rb1').setText(member1);
  var radio2 = app.createRadioButton('rb2').setText(member2);
  var selectBtn = app.createButton("Select").setStyleAttribute("margin-left", "80px").setFocus(true);
  var cnclBtn = app.createButton("Cancel");
  var dlg = app.createDialogBox()
    .setModal(true)
    .setText("Select Member")
    .setTitle("Select Member")
    .setPopupPosition(200, 200);  //PopupPosition does not work
  hPanel.add(selectBtn)
    .add(cnclBtn);
  vPanel.add(msg)
    .add(radio1)
    .add(radio2)
    .add(hPanel);
  dlg.add(vPanel);
  dlg.show();
  app.add(dlg);

  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `setPopupPosition` works only when the popup is created in a `handler` function.... I know it seems weird but in a couple of script I wrote I use it without issue in handler and it doesn't work if I copy/paste it in a `doGet` function....

Anyway, I don't know how you're going to use it in your real code but in the mean time you could position it with **style attributes**...

This [code works](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwXroGumhF7kbHpGlykXLwsyeTOl4xW7RU2vE6lrlQSe2xn5hVM/exec) :

```
function doGet() {
  var member1 = "Member1";
  var member2 = "Member2";
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var vPanel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('vPanel').setSpacing(10);
  var hPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel().setId('hPanel').setSpacing(10);
  var msg = app.createHTML("Which member's information do you want to update?");
  var radio1 = app.createRadioButton('rb1').setText(member1);
  var radio2 = app.createRadioButton('rb2').setText(member2);
  var selectBtn = app.createButton("Select").setStyleAttribute("margin-left", "80px").setFocus(true);
  var cnclBtn = app.createButton("Cancel");
  var dlg = app.createDialogBox()
    .setModal(true)
    .setText("Select Member")
    .setTitle("Select Member")
    .setStyleAttributes({'margin-top':200,'margin-left':200})
    .setPopupPosition(200, 200);  //PopupPosition does not work
  hPanel.add(selectBtn)
    .add(cnclBtn);
  vPanel.add(msg)
    .add(radio1)
    .add(radio2)
    .add(hPanel);
  dlg.add(vPanel);
  dlg.show();
  app.add(dlg);

  return app;
}
```

btw, your radioButtons won't work as it is, they must have the same name to behave as they are supposed to. There is an open issue on that subject and a couple of workaround as well. ([issue 506](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=506))